# Prior binary star system as possible explanation of high-velocity Type II Supernovae remnants

Tags: astronomy, supernova

From wikipedia(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova) :-

"A long-standing puzzle surrounding Type II supernovae is why the compact object remaining after the explosion is given a large velocity away from the epicentre;[96] pulsars, and thus neutron stars, are observed to have high velocities, and black holes presumably do as well, although they are far harder to observe in isolation. The initial impetus can be substantial, propelling an object of more than a solar mass at a velocity of 500 km/s or greater. This indicates an asymmetry in the explosion, but the mechanism by which momentum is transferred to the compact object remains a puzzle."

My Question:- 
Could the remnant compact high-velocity object simply be the surviving member of a binary pair, flying off at a tangent from the original locality after the companion star has blown away in a supernova?

Comment: No. The observed object that is moving away is the result of a Type II supernovae: the neutron star.

Comment: What if original pair comprised a stable fast-moving neutron star and a star which supernova'ed (Type II-P) leaving a small undetected neutron star, black hole or no remnant (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova see Table:Core collapse scenarios by mass and metallicity, based on Heger et al 2003 paper).

Comment: You are conflating Types here. Type II SNe are caused by *single* stars, Type I SNe occur in *binary* systems.

Comment: Sorry I put the wrong link for the 1st wikipedia article.  I did not initially mean to bring Type I supernovae into the discussion.  How can we be sure that any particular supernova is from a progenitor star which does not have a small binary partner.

Comment: We can tell from the physics if the explosion mechanism. Type II are caused by the collapsed core and does not need a binary. I am not entirely sure, but I think high-mass binaries are extremely rare compared to the number of neutron stars we know about.

Comment: You know more than me but logically it appears to me that although Type II mechanism does not NEED a binary that does not preclude some Type II progenitors from having a binary partner which survives (maybe "damaged" somehow) and goes runaway. I dont understand the significance of the ratio (hmb:ns) in your last sentence.

Comment: A Type I SNe destroys its precursor, Type II do not (hence the NS or BH). If the NS/BH gets a velocity kick, the companion would as well and I don't think any stars have been observed moving with such kicks in the vicinity of a SNR or NS.

Comment: If the Type II SN reduces a 10sm (solar mass) star to a very low-mass NS/BH (e.g. 0.1sm) and the companion was a high-mass NS (e.g. 2sm) then both stars will get a velocity kick but only the latter will be observed moving fast away from the scene.

Comment: No black hole can be that small (something like 3sm is the cutoff). Conservation of momentum would say that the smaller star would have a larger kick than the larger star. And, AFAIK, all NS are X-ray emitters, so we should observe it regardless of its size.

Comment: OK forget BH as product, keep 0.1sm NS. Wikipedia: Non-rotating and non-accreting NSs are virtually undetectable.  9.9sm of ejecta continue to contribute to system momentum. The companion merely retains most of its linear orbital velocity at "moment of release" when ejecta shell moves outside of it. No kick from the other star is required.

Comment: In retrospect, yes the companion would have the linear velocity; not sure what I was thinking. However, this appears to defeat your hypothesis as the companion cannot be given the kick (which comes from an asymmetry in the explosion); the high-velocity object *must* be the remnant of the star that exploded.

Comment: Companion doesnt need a kick if it already has high orbital velocity.  In my model (before explosion) a max distance of 100 MKm and elliptical orbits can give max velocity of companion = c. 500kps.  No need for explosion asymmetry.

Comment: Well then it just boils down to the fact that you're basically proposing an idea can't be observationally verified. Sure, it could be nice, but without any sort of proof for it, it's not really any better than the current model.

Comment: It could be verified if the companion 2sm NS was observable before and after the explosion. Not very likely perhaps.  But anyway isnt it a feasible and simple theoretical solution to the cited "long-standing problem"?

Comment: It could be verified a few hundred years from now when we have observations of a recent, galactic type ii event before and long after ( ns would need to move past the ejecta). Occam's razor would point to a single star, rather than a more complex situation you describe.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos OK Many thanks for your help. I will make an answer.

Comment: @KyleKanos why "NS would need to move past the ejecta"?  The effect would occur as soon as ejecta (30,000 kps) moved passed the ns (500 kps).  This could be observed on Earth within a year of the SN event light arrival at Earth for a SN event which happened a few hundred years ago and whose pre-SN-event history we have been observing for a few years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the original hypothesis is YES it seems feasible but the most-likely explanation is  asymmetry (due to some as-yet undiscovered cause) in the supernova explosion of a single progenitor star.

A simplified example model of the original hypothesis expanded and constrained is as follows:-

An original binary system comprises a primary star of approximately 10sm (solar masses) and a smaller companion neutron star of approximately 2 sm. Their orbits are such that the companion attains orbital velocities of up to 500kps, this could be achieved with a maximum separation of 100 MKm.

Then the primary explodes as a supernova leaving a small (e.g. 1sm) remnant neutron star not visible from earth.  The 9sm of ejecta forms an expanding spherical shell which quickly (up to 30,000 kps) moves away from the epicentre.  Once inside the shell the companion star feels no net gravitational force from it.  Therefore the companion star is quickly "released" from most of its previous gravitational bond and flies off with the linear velocity it possessed at the "moment" of explosion but held back somewhat by attraction to the remnant neutron star.  For some reason the companion star is visible from earth after the explosion, maybe it retains or acquires rotation or an accretion disk.

So from earth we would see an expanding shell of supernovae ejecta, no visible remnant at the core and a "runaway" neutron star heading at high velocity away from the epicentre.